# Java ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent equivalent for AtomicReference

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm looking for code equivalent to the following:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<int, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.computeIfAbsent(key, n -> f(n));
```

Where `f(n)` is HTTP network call and blocking for the result

Bur referring to single element held in `AtomicReference<Object>` where I need to ensure `f` is called only once upon even if multiple threads do the access concurrently.
I tried using `compareAndSet` but this doesn't allow lambda passing.
Does `updateAndGet` achieve that? Its documentation mentions

> The function should be side-effect-free, since it may be re-applied when attempted updates fail due to contention among threads.

Which doesn't seem to fill the need of invoking `f` only once.

Comment: You can not define a `ConcurrentHashMap<int, Object>`; Generics do not support primitive types as type argument. Besides that, the answer is that `AtomicReference` does not support locking.

Comment: Please provide an example implementation of f(n)'s purpose so that your question can be more clear.

Comment: @Holger yes my original code isn't with Object but with actual class. Doesn't AtomicReference provide the ability to set and get values in a thread safe manner similarly to ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: `AtomicReference` does provide thread safe updates, but only lock free. `ConcurrentHashMap` provides lock free `get` and `put` and updates like `computeIfAbsent` using locking. As you found out yourself, `AtomicReference`’s `updateAndGet` does not lock but re-evaluate the function if there was an overlapping update. • The problem with your posted `ConcurrentHashMap<int, Object>` is not the `Object` value but the impossible `int` key type.

Comment: Guava's `Suppliers.memoize(supplier)` is typically what I use for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like a concurrent lazy initializer.
It is possible to achieve this using:

1. If your requirement is to have only 1 instance in an application, you can use a thread-safe singleton. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

   ```
    public class Something {
         private final Result result;
         private Something() {
              result = f();
         }

         private static class LazyHolder {
              public static final Something INSTANCE = new Something();
         }

         public static Something getInstance() {
                 return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
         }
   }
   ```
2. If you want to have it in different places of your application, you can use:

**Apache Commons Lang** [ConcurrentInitializer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/ConcurrentInitializer.html) like [LazyInitializer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/LazyInitializer.html):

```
   ConcurrentInitializer<> lazyInitializer = new LazyInitializer<Result>() {

          @Override
          protected Foo initialize() throws ConcurrentException {
               return f();
          }
   };
```

Get instance

```
  Result instance = lazyInitializer.get();
```

**Google's Guava** [link](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize(com.google.common.base.Supplier)):

```
Supplier<Result> resultSupplier = Suppliers.memoize(new Supplier<Result>() {
    public Result get() {
        return f();
    }
});
```

3. Yon can create your own concurrent lazy initalizer in lock-free manner.

   ```
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
    import java.util.function.Supplier;

    public class LazyConcurrentSupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> {

        static class Container<T> {
            public static final int NULL_PHASE = -1, CREATING_PHASE = 0, CREATED = 1;

            final int i;
            final T value;
            public Container(int i, T value) {
                this.i = i;
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

        private final Container<T> NULL = new Container<>(Container.NULL_PHASE, null),
                CREATING = new Container<>(Container.CREATING_PHASE, null);

        private final AtomicReference<Container<T>> ref = new AtomicReference<>(NULL);

        private final Supplier<T> supplier;

        public LazyConcurrentSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier) {
            this.supplier = supplier;
        }

        @Override
        public T get() {
            Container<T> prev;
            do {
                if (ref.compareAndSet(NULL, CREATING)) {
                    T res = supplier.get();
                    ref.set(new Container<>(Container.CREATED, res));
                    return res;
                } else {
                    prev = ref.get();
                    if (prev.i == Container.CREATED) {
                        return prev.value;
                    }
                }
            } while (prev.i < Container.CREATED);
            return prev.value;
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think you want to avoid doing the HTTP request multiple times.

You could have a map of FutureTask(s) that asynchronously performs the HTTP request for you. In this way, if a thread tries to computeIfAbsent it will see the FutureTask created by another thread even if the HTTP operation is not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `AtomicBoolean` with an initial value of `true` and allow each thread should call `AtomicBoolean::getAndSet` with the value `false`. If the return value is `true` then you execute your function.

This will ensure that the call is only made once since only the first thread will succeed.